# Enable to create a signed apk in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "polarmagic.atlasgames.com.polarmagic.Home"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    // AdMob
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
}
```

Comment: can you specify your question in a proper manner!!!

Comment: use this link and follow the steps to generate signed  apk https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: what is a problem? Whare is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not generated a signed APK from this window?

you will get a pop-up dialog you need to fill its info to get a keystore

[image]

in case you don't have a key store you can create a new one from here.

you will need to fill in some data and it is done.

[image]

from docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: <img src="https://imgur.com/a/fF62JDS" alt="enter image description here">

Comment: <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/fF62JDS"><a href="//imgur.com/fF62JDS"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: what you mean bro?